# button is taking time to load/show Image while pressing button sencha touch2

Tags: sencha-touch, extjs, sencha-touch-2

i have a button, i want to show to user in page load normal button icon, once he pressing button i need to show him pressing button icon. i have achieved this one by setting cls for button. i am using sass styles, accessing image url path from the server. it is working fine as per my requirement. ***but during first time load the page it is shows normal button icon its fine, once i pressing the button it takes some time means(5-10seconds) next it shows pressing button icon, this is happening for first time only. why it is taking first time load this much time for to load change pressing icon?***  next time it will work fine change the icon immediately during pressing button. Can have any another best way to achieve this one?

Here is my code:

```
 {
                        xtype: "button",                           
                        cls: 'aboutclsT',
                        handler: function () {

                        }

                    }
```

In my app.scss

```
.aboutclsT{
 background: url('http://src.sencha.io/100/http://s11.postimage.org/dg1zv08j7/about.png') !important;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 height: 133px;
 width: 100px;

 }

 .aboutclsT.x-button-pressing{
 background: url('http://src.sencha.io/100/http://s7.postimage.org/4vy4hg72z/about_active.png') !important;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 height: 133px;
 width: 100px;
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

loading the button image from an URL and the first call downloads it. After that the browser has it cached and so it is taking time. **If you base64 it in CSS it will be fast all the time**.